# Is There a Way to "Self-Update" r packages that haven't Updated in Years?

Tags: r, updates, r-package

So, I've come across this problem multiple times: I find a "one-of-a-kind" package that should work beautifully for what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the package is unavailable for the updated version of R. Many times, looking at the packages, they haven't been updated in YEARS! Though one could downgrade R Studio to a compatible version, that's really annoying and/or you may be using a different package's library that is not compatible with the downgraded version.

That being said, and speaking more generally, is there a way to "self-update" a package? Meaning, make it suitable for running on current R versions?

So if you have any resources, recommendations, etc., PLEASE let me know (I'm starting to get desperate). Thank you in advance, y'all!

Info: I'm currently running R version 3.4.4 on MacOS Mojave (10.14.2), if it matters.

Comment: I don't know if this is the source of the problem, but why don't you update your R to 3.5?

Comment: PoGibas, the problem I'm having troubles with refers to the fact that the packages are out of date (not the R version that I'm running). Basically, they're like the packages that get abandoned and left to phase out of use as R/RStudio continues to update.

Comment: Where do these packages come from? I cant find a trace of them on CRAN, github, or bioconductor

Comment: So I fixed the issue that I was having. I mistakenly posted as if it were an R package problem, when it was actually a problem with my R-java interface not linking the two Java modules/viewers (JChemPaint and Jmol) back into R Studio. So it's all taken care of. I've instead updated to speak more generally about self-updating "abandoned" r packages.

Comment: Hi there, so the Java JDK requirement was met. R wasn't reading it in correctly as it said something like, "You don't have a full JDK. JRE was not sufficient," but it was corrected, the package was loaded in, but the further Java elements were omitted, as the viewers of those Java elements were not compatible with the R-Java interface that I was using. So in the end, it wasn't the package I was using, but rather the Java elements that I was trying to patch in through the R-Java interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons for package rot is the CRAN requirement that packages pass the stringent compatibility tests with each R update. You are running a version of R that's almost a year old (despite having a current version of your OS). Some people maintain several versions of R going back years, but most do not. In some case you will be able to download a `*.tar.gz` version of the package and use either a Terminal-mediated session using" `R CMD INSTALL p"/path/to/pkg-name.tag.gz"` or using in an R console: `install.packages("path/to/pkg-name.tar.gz", repo=NULL, dependencies=TRUE, type="source")`

You should of course study the DESCRIPTION file for the pkg and make sure you have need compiler and external system resources available. (Presumably the requirement for a Java runtime environment was in the DESCRPTION file?) The question as it stands might be useful, but it really quite vague in the absence of a specific package to be used for demonstration and testing.